# Start Hyper-V VM using desktop shortcut

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I would like to start a hyper-v VM using a desktop shortcut and then controll it using Windows Remote Desktop. The internet says I should create a shortcut pointing here:

```
C:\\Windows\System32\vmconnect.exe localhost 'name of VM'
```

When I click the shortcut a hyper-v window showing the remote connection to the VM pops up. But I want to use Windows Remote Desktop instead. How would I have to change the shortcut to start the VM, but not open the Hyper-V window?

Mayber there is another .exe that just starts the server or someone has a shell script

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe /v [locally accessible VM IP Address]`

Comment: that's just initiating the communication between the VM and Windows Remote Desktop. But not starting the VM, right?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a shortcut with RMB in any directory. And then type

```
vmconnect.exe 127.0.0.1 "My VM name"
```

127.0.0.1 is the IP address of the computer that runs the command, if targeting a remote server that IP would be used in stead.

This pops up the Window of the VM which connects or shows it is not running yet, and then you can press start.

Comment: For me this didn't work with the 127.0.0.1 IP for some reason, but worked with `localhost`! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple PS script can do that. Can just start the script through a shortcut.

```
$vmname = "MyVM"
Get-VM -ComputerName localhost -Name $vmname | Where-Object {$_.State -ne 'Running'} | Start-VM
& "$env:windir\system32\mstsc.exe" /v:$vmname
```

Comment: didn't quite work for me. I was unable to start the Remote Desktop connection by using the name of the VM. I had to use the IP Address like this: ```$vmname = "name of VM" $vmip = "locally accessible IP Address of VM" Get-VM -ComputerName localhost -Name $vmname | Where-Object {$_.State -ne 'Running'} | Start-VM & "$env:windir\system32\mstsc.exe" /v $vmip```

Comment: Your Host might not be able to resolve the hostnames of your VMs then.